# Menu dropdown not working after adding slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

Kindly check this page: https://cutt.ly/mDYu9Nr (I have removed the unwanted section here to make things less complicated).

After adding thumbnail carousal website top menu had stopped working.

After some digs I found out that "slick.min.js" is giving me trouble. If I removed this script menu dropdown work properly.

It will be great if someone help me in this regards. I have already spent 2 days and tried almost every solution which are on internet like adjusting JS sequence, css solution etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have shared the html page link in the message body.

Comment: All the necessary information for your question needs to be here. Please, no links to external sites.